# How to secure socket.io from code injection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, serverside-javascript

So i'm developing a socket.io real-time web-app.
The first concern of mine was "What if some evil-minded user tries to inject some code via Dev Tools or Firebug?" and i've got my answer here on SO. My next concern is: "What if some evil-minded user tries to inject some code via chat and/or other form of string inputs?" and I've came to the conclusion that I can't figure this out by myself. I know that I can use regex to find if the user is trying to inject code but once the code is sent to server and stored to a string it is executed. (ex: `var data = " *asd "; while(1);* "`; [ where the user sent string is the one between * ] ). So my question is: **How can i prevent this?** in other words **How do I sanitize the user input?**

Comment: you have to treat all user input as string

Comment: What do you mean by that? I do treat all user input as string.. Sorry, i seem not to understand what you imply.

Comment: if the input is always treated as string, the user enter `while(1);` all that is going to happen is the other user in the chat will see `while(1);`

Comment: Yeah i know that. But isn't this the same problem as in XSS? If he enters " doesn't he end the string? I'm very confused as how this is treated by the server.

Comment: if he enters you can encode your string using `encodeURIComponent()`

Comment: If i do this in the client could he tamper it?

Comment: you can do it in Node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can encode the user input using [encodeURIComponent(userstring);](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Example:

```
var userData = encodeURIComponent(" *asd "; while(1);* ");
```